# Find the nearest integer solution to a linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, regular-expressions, finite-automata

I am interested in calculating the maximum number of strings of a fixed length that can be generated by a regular expression.

If I have the regular expression `((a|b)c)+`

How would I find out how many strings I can build from that not exceeding a number, say 5?

In this particular case, I can't build a string that fits the regex that is exactly 5 characters, but I can find strings that are 4 characters, or 6.

I think the linear equation would be something like

```
((a*x + b*y)+c)*z = I

with restrictions:
c=1
x>=0, y>= 0, z >=0
if(x = 0, y > 0)
if(y = 0, x >0
```

If this solution is not an integer, is there any way to find the nearest integer solution, or do I just need to solve the equation for different I values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make the observation that each new pair of letters allow a doubling of the number of combinations.

You can write it as a linear least squares optimization.

$$\min_v \|\bf Mv\|$$
I make $\bf M$ unnecessarily large so pattern gets easier to spot:
$${\bf M} = \left[\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
0&2&0&-1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&2&0&-1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&2&0&-1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&2&0&-1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&2&0&-1&0
\end{array}\right]$$

**But** we also need to enforce a boundary condition: for example that there are 2 2-letter solutions. We can do this by adding a term

$$+\epsilon {\bf C}\|{\bf v}-[0,2,0,\cdots]^T\|_2^2$$

Where $\bf C$ is the diagonal matrix 0 everywhere except but at ${\bf C}_{22} = 1$. This will force second position of $\bf v$ to be 2.

Now the actual answer would be to sum up the solution vector since we want the sum of all combinations of 1,2,3,4,5 length. But that is easily done when we have solved the system.

---

**EDIT: Variations**: if we had for example $(a|b)+$ we would have:

$${\bf M} = \left[\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
2&-1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&2&-1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&2&-1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&2&-1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&2&-1&0
\end{array}\right]$$

Because then *each* new letter could take any of the 2 new values. No need to hop over every second letter with a "0" in the equation system which would have been forced to be "c" in the previous expression.

If we had $((a|b|c)d)+$ we would have:

$${\bf M} = \left[\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
0&3&0&-1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&3&0&-1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&3&0&-1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&3&0&-1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&3&0&-1&0
\end{array}\right]$$

Because there would be 3 new cases to multiply with for each new occurrence of $((a|b|c)d)$

Comment: Hi - thank you for the input. Can you explain to me what the terms in the rows of M represent, exactly?

Comment: Yes, there is one 2 and one -1 in each row. So each row is an equation saying if we add two more letters, then the number of possible solutions should be doubled: $v_{2+k} = 2v_k$ or rewritten $2v_k-v_{2+k} = 0$. We do get double number of solutions because for each of the previous solutions we can choose either $a$ or $b$ for first letter.

Comment: The first row says if we have 4 letters (fourth column), then the number of solutions should be equal to the double of if we had 2 letters (second column).

Comment: When you say "each new pair of letters allow a doubling" are you talking about a pair of letters added to the string I am attempting to match with the regex? Is this a "pair" specifically because in this regex, the shortest matches will be 2 letters?

Comment: It's because for this regex each new time ((a|b)c) occurs it can be two cases ac or bc. This doubles the number of combinations compared to however many it were if we had one less ((a|b)c).

Comment: If we had for example ((a|b|c)d)+ it would be [3 0 -1] in each row instead since it would be multiplied by 3 instead of 2.

Comment: Ok - i think understand that side of the equation. On your notation for C, is that denoting the 2-norm squared?

Comment: Do you care to generalize this answer? I could modify the question for the general case of deterministic regular expressions

Comment: I can add some stuff and examples to make it easier to understand. But expanding it to all regular expressions will probably be a bit too big for an answer. I can maybe write it down and give a link later.